# mostrar solo dia mes y año

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, jade

Hola necesito saber como puedo "acortar" una fecha que actualmente viene con este formato desde la BD

```
Thu Dec 31 2009 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Hora estándar Montañas (México))
```

para solo me muestre dia mes y año que quedara algo asi 31 dic (o con numero 12) 2009 
el codigo con el que lleno el campo de la tabla es este (me gustaria saber si hay alguna propiedad que se le pueda agregar en el style del td)o como convertir el dato desde la consulta sql

```
(SELECT fecha FROM pedido)
```

---

```
    table#tabla
     thead
     tr
      th fecha
    tbody
    each val in datos.rows
       tr
        td(style='background-color:243,243,243;') #{val.fecha}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a usar la libreria [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Por ejemplo:

```
 #{moment(val.fecha).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
```

Para poder usar moment con pug añade la siguiente linea de código al fichero app.js de tu aplicación

```
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TRUNC(fecha) FROM pedido;
```

Otra forma que puedes hacerlo es usando.

```
SELECT to_char(fecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM pedido;
```

Donde fecha es tu campo de tu tabla pedido.

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida te comento que aunque esta pudiera ser la solución en SO se esperan respuestas acompañadas de código y explicación, de otro modo se consideran de baja calidad; te recomiendo leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] antes de que recibas mas votos negativos